# xcopy batch issue

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I want to copy a set of subfolders where `name contains` items on a list. The list has a set of codes (e.g. `ABC1`, `ABC2`) but the folders are named `ABC1_revised_2018`, etc. My batch file I put together is below. What I am getting a `'"Usebackq tokens=^" was unexpected'` error.

```
@ECHO ON
SET FileList=C:\filelist.txt
SET Source=C:\Files
SET Destination=C:\Files-Parsed
FOR /D "USEBACKQ TOKENS=^" %%D IN ("%FileList%") DO XCOPY /E /F /D "%Source%\%%~D" "%Destination%\"
GOTO :EOF
```

I am attempting to use `^` to denote `match beginning of string` but that clearly isn't working. Any ideas? I have tried with a batch file and also line by line in cmd.

append

```
Folder
     -ABC1-text-date (this is a subfolder)
     -ABC2-text-date

filelist.txt only has values like ABC1, ABC2, etc. not exact matches does this help?
```

Comment: Did you meand `for /F …..` **also without the `^` from `TOKENS=^`**?

Comment: @Tiw `tokens` may only be a number. That was not the actual error.

Comment: @double-beep  Oh, I misread that as delims, oops...

Comment: @Tiw he probably **meant** `delims`, so you are right if so.

Comment: Sorry! They're subfolders in a dfs, edited to reflect that, hence the /d rather than /f. Including ^ because each folder name begins with a value from that list, but it's not an exact match.

Comment: Hi @Tiw, question appended with an example/explanation. Does that help?

Comment: Not sure how you know about all the `FOR` options but don't know that you can't mix them together.

Comment: @squashman https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html

Comment: So you just want to xcopy matching directories inside the file?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard yes, but the issue being the folder names are not exact matches

Comment: @sibelius3, you are using [FOR /D](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to recurse through directories and copy sub directories as per partial matches inside the file:

```
@echo off
set "FileList=C:\filelist.txt"
set "Source=C:\Files"
set "Destination=C:\Files-Parsed"
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%filelist%) do (
  pushd %source%
  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /ad "%%a*"') do xcopy /E /F /D "%%~fi" "%Destination%"
  popd
)
```

after getting the entry in the file, `for /d` will do a directory listing of the directory* in the source directory and physically copy the dir as `C:\source\*\ABC2018` etc.

Comment: thank you, this runs without errors, but doesn't seem to search subfolders. The subfolders I'm looking to copy would be found at c:\files\folder\abc1, etc. Would I need to adjust how I reference the source?

Comment: @sibelius ok did not know that. Will update answer now.